# How to create a deny policy to remove the OWNER role after X days

Tags: policy, identity-management

How to create a deny policy to remove the OWNER role after X days

```
gcloud iam policies create mi9-lda-dev-firebase-owner  --attachment-point=iam.cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/mi9-lda-dev-firebase --kind=denypolicies --policy-file=policy_owner.json
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.iam.policies.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Attachment point (iam.cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%2Fmi9-lda-dev-firebase) should be of the form > cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com//. For more information about the attachment point, visit https://cloud.google.com/iam/help/deny/attachment-point.